# I want to read a text file called input.txt(some name) and segregate the even and odd words into two different files names even.txt and odd.txt

Tags: c

Here is the code for the same .
Problem am facing is , am not able to write any thing on any of the files.
Kindly help resolving this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()

{
  FILE *fe;
  FILE *fo;
  FILE *fg;
  int i;
  int j,l;
  char ch;
  char tmp[100] ;

 fo = fopen("oddfile.txt","a");
 if (fo == NULL)
 {
  perror("ODDFILE");
 }
 fclose(fo);

 fe = fopen("evenfile.txt","a");
 if (fe == NULL)
 {
  perror("EVENFILE");
 }
 fclose(fe);

 fg = fopen("generalfile","r");
 if (fg == NULL)
 {
  perror("GENERALFILE");
 }

 while(ch = fgetc(fg)!=EOF)
 {
    if (ch != '\n' && ch != 't' && ch != ' ')
    {
        tmp[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }


    else 
    {
        printf("%s",tmp);
        l =strlen(tmp);
        j = l % 2;
        if (j == 0)
        {
          fe = fopen("evenfile.txt","ab");
            if (fe == NULL)
            {
                perror("EVENFILE");
             }  

         fwrite(&tmp,sizeof(tmp),1,fe);
         fclose(fe);

        }

        else
        {
            fo = fopen("oddfile.txt","ab");
            if (fo == NULL)
             {
                perror("ODDFILE");
             }
         fwrite(&tmp,sizeof(tmp),1,fo);
         fclose(fo);

        }
    }

 }

}
```

My code is compiling successfully but not able to get the desired output

Comment: Please compile with all warnings enabled, and fix these *obvious* issues first. From a glance: you are not initializing `i` anywhere; you are using `strlen` on a string that is not zero-terminated; writing `sizeof(tmp)` will not only save your string but garbage as well. (BTW: you don't *need* `strlen` -- with the correct procedure, `i` will already hold the word length.)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 while(ch = fgetc(fg)!=EOF)
```

to

```
 while( (ch = fgetc(fg)) !=EOF)
```

The precedence rules make the two behave differently.  The way you have it coded, `ch` is always set to either 0 or 1, neither of which is a printable character.

There's no reason to open the files multiple times.  Just open each output file once before the loop.  You would be wise to use `fprintf` rather than `fwrite`, and don't use the size of `tmp` as the length; you already calculated the length of the string, so use it!  You might also want to write a newline or some separator after each word.  And you really need to check for stack overflow and handle it if the input contains large words.  Blindly assuming that your input words will fit into a 100 character array is a disaster waiting to happen.  Just slightly worse than failing to put a null character at the end of the input and calling `strlen` on a character array that may not be a string.  (Which is another bug you have: you need to write a NULL into `tmp` at the end of the input.)

Also note that it is quite annoying to get an error message which reads:

```
ODDFILE: no such file or directory
```

if the file that the program actually cares about is not called "ODDFILE".

And, finally (although it is entirely possible there are more bugs in this short program), it would be a great idea to stop relying on behavior that exists in compilers merely for the purpose of conforming to standard practices from 1983.  Declare the main function properly as `int main( void )`, or (even better) use `int main( int argc, char **argv)` and allow the caller to specify input file names.  And return a value from main!  Turn up your compiler warnings as well, since they will give you useful information.